# Procesesar hilo por hilo en Android (tiempo de proceso)

Tags: android, android-studio, hilos

les vengo con una duda que me surge, a ver si me pueden orientar.

En la app, al apretar un botón, se suben unas fotos al storage de firebase, luego recupera las URL de las fotos y por último a través de un hashmap subo la info a la base datos cloud de firebase, todo eso lo hace perfecto la app, el detalle es que la URL de la foto, a la base de datos la sube como null, me di cuenta y es que se procesa todo tan rápido, que no da chance de crear la url.

la pregunta es la siguiente hay alguna manera de que se procese hilo por hilo, y hasta que no termine uno, no pase al otro...

primero que suba lad fotos al storage, luego al haberlas subido arranque el hilo de recibir las URL del storage de cada foto y luego al tenerlas ya descargada me imagino que en cache, justo luego arranque el hilo del hashmap y me suba todos los item a la base de datos.

espero se haya entendido mi duda, los leo chicos. y gracias de antemano

PD: Si, soy nuevo en esto.

---------- Codigo que funciona perfecto -------------

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_crearcampeonato);
    
            init();

 fotopersonaje1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    almacenador = String.valueOf(1);
                    currentImageView = fotopersonaje1;
    
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, ImageBack);
    
                    fotopersonaje1.setBorderWidth(7);
                    fotopersonaje1.setBorderColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.banner));
                 }
            });
    
    
            crear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

    
                    Funcionprincipal funcionprincipal = new Funcionprincipal();
                        funcionprincipal.execute();
 
                }
            });
    
        }
    
        private void init() {
    
            loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
    
            carpeta = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("fotos");
    
            crearpersonaje1 = findViewById(R.id.crearpersonaje1);
            fotopersonaje1 = findViewById(R.id.fotopersonaje1);
 
            crear = findViewById(R.id.btncrearcampeonato);
            mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        }
    
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
    
            if (requestCode == ImageBack && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null)
            {
                ImageUri = data.getData();
                CropImage.activity(ImageUri)
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                        .start(this);
            }
            if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode ==
                    RESULT_OK) {
                CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
                assert result != null;
                ImageResultadoUri = result.getUri();        }
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),
                        ImageResultadoUri);
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200,200,true);
    
                Glide.with(this).load(bitmap).into(currentImageView);
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("AlmacenadoUri", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor UriImagen = preferences.edit();
    
                UriImagen.putString(almacenador, ImageResultadoUri.toString());
                UriImagen.apply();
    
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
        }
    
        private class Funcionprincipal extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
        {
    
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
    
                loadingBar.show();
                loadingBar.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar_layout);
                loadingBar.setCancelable(false);
                loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                Objects.requireNonNull(loadingBar.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    
                nombre1 = crearpersonaje1.getText().toString();

            }
    
    
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    
                recibiendofoto1();
    
   
                return "finalizado";
            }
    
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
    
                        Map<String, Object> campeonatoMap = new HashMap<>();
                        campeonatoMap.put("nombre1", nombre1);
                        campeonatoMap.put("imagen1", url1);
    
                        mFirestore.collection("Post").add(postMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                Toast.makeText(crearcampeonato.this, "perfecto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                String mensaje = e.toString();
                                Toast.makeText(crearcampeonato.this, "Advertencia: " + mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
    
    
            }
    
            @Override
            protected void onCancelled() {
                super.onCancelled();
            }
        }
    
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        private void recibiendofoto1() {
            if (ImageResultadoUri!=null){
    
                SharedPreferences preferences1 = getSharedPreferences("AlmacenadoUri", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String uriimagen1 = preferences8.getString("1", "error");
    
                final StorageReference FilePath8 = carpeta.child(Objects.requireNonNull(nombre1+"1"+uniqueID));
                FilePath1.putFile(Uri.parse(Objects.requireNonNull(uriimagen1))).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        FilePath8.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                url1 = uri.toString();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(crearcampeonato.this, getString(R.string.error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
    
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(crear.this, getString(R.string.error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    
    }
```

PD: Alli agregue el codigo, funciona perfectamente, El detalle es que se procesa el HashMap tan rapido que se guarda en la vase de datos la url de la imagen en NULL, si funciona, porque lo probe con un toast, y el toast me da la URL, si tarda un unos segundos en salir el toast, pero funciona, tambiern lo probe con Shared Preferencia a ver que valor me guardaba y al revisar el Shared preferencia tiene la URL perfecta, el detalle es eso es HashMap se genera tan rapido que no da chance a obtener la URL antes de crearse.m Espero pueda ayudarme

Comment: Si, se puede, pero me gustaría ver tu código para ver si te puedo decir la posible solución

Comment: Hola agrega tu código por favor, recuerda agregar información necesaria que ayude a la comunidad a saber cual es el problema, revisar [ask], saludos

Comment: @rockbass2560 Hola ya subi el codigo que funciona perfectamente

Comment: @Jorgesys Hola ya subi el codigo que funciona perfectamente, espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Una forma sencilla de realizar tareas asíncronas en Android como si fuese código síncrono, es usando las suspend functions de las corrutinas.  Cada función suspendida se ejecuta en el orden en que la pongas e incluso puedes realizar dos acciones a la vez si lo necesitas.  Otra opción es emplear Threads pero personalmente me parece más complejo y por último una forma sencilla pero menos elegante es usando callbacks.

Comment: hola @Manuel_Mato gracias por tu sugerencia, leí lo de las corrutinas, no conocía de ellas, pero creo que solo funciona en kotlin, aclárame eso porfa.